# Flutter "Unable to load file" file from file picker

Tags: flutter, dart

## **I am using flutter for a windows app , and I need to get a XML file with file picker package then use it to get a string of it**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:bitsdojo_window/bitsdojo_window.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test2/attribute.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './second.dart';

import './items.dart';
import 'first.dart';
import "package:hovering/hovering.dart";

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
    theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 21, 24)),
  ));
  doWhenWindowReady(() {
    var initialsize = Size(1200, 720);
    appWindow.minSize = initialsize;
    //appWindow.size = initialsize;
    appWindow.title = "Atlantas XML";
    appWindow.maximize();
    appWindow.show();
  });
}

//-----------------------------------------------
//IGNORE EVERYTHING UP UNTIL YOU SEE NEXT COMMENT
//-----------------------------------------------

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: WindowBorder(
        width: 2,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 82, 249),
              child: WindowTitleBarBox(
                  child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(child: MoveWindow()),
                  MinimizeWindowButton(),
                  MaximizeWindowButton(),
                  CloseWindowButton(),
                ],
              )),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment:
                  MainAxisAlignment.center, //Center Row contents horizontally,
              crossAxisAlignment:
                  CrossAxisAlignment.center, //Center Row contents vertically,
              children: [
                Expanded(flex: 2, child: Container()),
                Expanded(flex: 3, child: Image.asset("assets/img/atlas1.png")),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                        .center, //Center Column contents vertically,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                        .center, //Center Column contents horizontally,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        "Chose:",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 85, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: HoverButton(
                            minWidth: 400,
                            onpressed: () {
                              _pickfile();
                            },
                            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 82, 249),
                            hoverColor: Colors.white,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            shape: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 5.0),
                            ),
                            hoverShape: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 82, 249),
                                  width: 5.0),
                            ),
                            hoverTextColor:
                                const Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 82, 249),
                            child: const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "New XML file",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                      
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(flex: 2, child: Container()),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//-----------------------------------------------
//Problem comes here
//-----------------------------------------------

  void _pickfile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform
        .pickFiles(type: FileType.custom, allowedExtensions: ['xml']);

    if (result != null) {
      File file = File(result.files.single.path.toString());
      print(file.toString());
      print(result.names);

      final newfile = await savefileTemp(file);

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Testing(
            xmlfile: newfile,
          ),
        ),
      );
      //File file = File(result.files.first.path);
    }
  }

  Future<File> savefileTemp(File file) async {
    final appStorage = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final newfile = File('${appStorage.path}\\temp.xml');

    return File(file.path).copy(newfile.path);
  }
}
```

**After this code is executed the file is sent to another page where I use the file here :**

```
String xmlstring = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(widget.xmlfile.path);
```

**and I get the error : "Unable to load file" . I know that DefaultAssetBundle is looking at my assets folder but I cant find a way to pass the file and use it . Either being in cashe of getting it from external storage**

I want to get a file from file picker and use it with loadString function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer by accident
you have to change this:

```
var raw = xml.XmlDocument.parse(xmlstring);
```

into this:

```
var raw = xml.XmlDocument.parse(widget.xmlfile.readAsStringSync());
```